# How can I flash a new radio firmware on my s3 neo trough my custom recovery?

Tags: rooting

My USB stopped working after I installed a new ROM on my device and I figured I must have messed-up the radio-firmware. Regardless to if that's true or not, I would still like to know how I can install and where I can find an appropriate radio-firmware for my Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo device.

Comment: What kind of reasoning led you to suspect the *radio* when *USB* is down? Shouldn't you first blame the ROM instead?

Comment: @AndyYan I have installed 3 other roms since then. Also mounting mtp directly in the recovery doesnt work either. To me it seems that the hardware abstraction layer is messed up and now I need to flash a new one. From what I read the radio-firmware is what I am looking for. It even says it in the tag for it on this site.

Comment: The radio firmware has nothing to do with the USB, that is purely kernel drivers, whether from the boot image, recovery, or  bootloader, all high-functions of USB are handled by the kernel loaded at that time. That said,  since you have flashed 3 different ROMs and USB continues to fail (all 3 would have different kernels), I would look at hardware issues. Cable, port, bad mainboard, etc. maybe the cause. A quick flash back to stock should tell you, although if you can't use flash in Download Mode that pretty much signifies somekind of hardware issue.